# How can i add an entire folder to a ZIP archive in batch?

Tags: batch-file, zip

Can someone tell me How can i add an entire folder to a ZIP archive in batch?

And what software can i use to do that?

My folder is named FILES and it should be added to an archive called FILES.ZIP
Note add all the files in it like this:

/FILE1
/FILE2

not like

/FILES/FILE1
/FILES/FILE2

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? http://www.info-zip.org/

```
C:>dir test
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is F8F0-B00C

 Directory of C:\Users\pwatson\test

2015-05-28  06:56    <DIR>          .
2015-05-28  06:56    <DIR>          ..
2015-05-28  06:55               263 .profile
2015-05-28  06:56                74 .sh_history
               2 File(s)            337 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  355,497,390,080 bytes free

C:>zip newone.zip test\*
  adding: test/.profile (164 bytes security) (deflated 33%)
  adding: test/.sh_history (164 bytes security) (deflated 58%)

16:31:16.42  C:\Users\pwatson
C:>unzip -l newone.zip
Archive:  newone.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      263  2015-05-28 06:55   test/.profile
       74  2015-05-28 06:56   test/.sh_history
---------                     -------
      337                     2 files
```

Or, do you mean like this?

```
C:>cd test

C:>zip newtwo.zip *
  adding: .profile (164 bytes security) (deflated 33%)
  adding: .sh_history (164 bytes security) (deflated 58%)

C:>unzip -l newtwo.zip
Archive:  newtwo.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      263  2015-05-28 06:55   .profile
       74  2015-05-28 06:56   .sh_history
---------                     -------
      337                     2 files
```